# Should I have old film developed

Tags: film

I found some old film in my closet. Kodak Advantix from 2001. Is it worth the effort to try and get it devloped, or should i just dispose of it.

Comment: Should you pay to have your film developed? Only you can say. Or are you asking whether any usable images at all can be developed from 18-year-old film?

Comment: And see also: [Is it worth trying to process film shot in 1989? (Fall of the Berlin Wall)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95593)

Comment: The effort is literally just money and what it would take for you to research and then post the rolls to a service. Only you can say if it is worth it. If the question is "could there be salvageable information on these rolls" the answer is "yes, probably; but we can't know until they are developed"

Comment: Another aspect though, if you found a roll of film YOU did not expose, is how to handle the situation from an ethical standpoint..... especially if you have no idea what is on the film, and especially if giving the film away to process and you do not know who will handle it!

Comment: @rackandboneman half the fun of buying that old movie camera at the antique shop is in getting the used reel developed. Never know, could have the key to the JFK assassination on it or something.

Answer (score 3):

Old expired film is probably going to have very poor color and contrast, with lots of grain.

Still, I think it would be interesting to see what you have on that roll. It won't cost too much to get it developed/processed, and a digital scan made of each negative. Then you can use editing software to improve image or turn it into a B&W photo.

Answer (score -2):

> is it worth the effort to try and get it developed?

With overwhelming strain to my phalanges, carpels, and retinas, I managed to google "where to get Aps Film developed." This place came up first: https://processonephoto.com/mail-order-advantix-aps-film-developing.htm

You will have to take a deep breath, steel your mind, prepare your body...You will have to journey, from the depths of your home to the local post office box in order to mail your film. Then you'll have to wait. And wait. And then finally, you will have your images. This journey will tax your legs, your arms, your patience, and your soul. But there is no other way.

> or should i just dispose of it?

Okay, I guess there is another way. Toss it in the fire. Much less effort.

Comment: I would expect that any business with a darkroom (eg camera store with attached professional lab) can hand develop and scan the film, even if it might not be super cheap and they might not be able to return it rewound into the APS cartridge (who cares!)? It is still C41 film, if you really found no one willing to develop it, you can get C41 development kit yourself....

Comment: @rackandboneman Oh, I completely agree with you, in case that wasn't apparent through the snark. The cost and effort of C-41 is so minimal, *not* developing it is really just an excuse. #LeaveNoRollBehind

Comment: Why the DVs? ... Maybe b/c burning film is bad for the environment?  But may not be much worse than the chemicals required to develop it.

Comment: @xiota sarcasm/snark and SE don't go well. I'm surprised someone hasn't flagged this for removal tbh.